# Get users from table by date fields

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table with date format YYYY-MM-DD and fields are:

```
user | assign_date | removal_date  
 A |  2020-01-01 | null  
 B |  2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05
 C |  2020-01-10 | null
```

How using Laravel Query Builder or simple SQL query I can get users to compare assign_date and removal date with selected_date?
The example of the needed results.

```
selected date | users  
2020-01-03 | A,B (user C has not recruited yet)
2020-01-06 | A  (user C has not recruited yet and user B has already been fired)
2020-01-11 | A,C  (user C has already recruited, but user B has already been fired)
```

Comment: I think you can use eloquent and query builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have nullable date type field.

So you can filter like this:

#### For Eloquent:

```php
Model::where('assinged_date', '<=', $selected_date)
       ->where(function($q) use ($selected_date) {
            $q->whereNull('removal_date')
              ->orWhere('removal_date', '>=', $selected_date);
         })
```

#### For QueryBuilder:

```php
DB::table('table_name')->where('assinged_date', '<=', $selected_date)
                     ->where(function($q) use ($selected_date) {
                          $q->whereNull('removal_date')
                            ->orWhere('removal_date', '>=', $selected_date);
                       })
```

Comment: I try check it in tinker like this:  $date = new Carbon\Carbon('2019-12-26'), RefCommittee::where('assignment_date', '<=', $date)->where(function($q) use ($date) { $q->whereNull('removal_date')->orWhere('removal_date', '>=', $date);}) and it returned Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#3158} with empty

Comment: please put a default date value for removal_date to avoid error with your query.

Comment: What is a default value should be for a removal_date ? For example? After all, an user can be hired and never fired

Comment: @MaximStogniy can u post your record that you think that it need to be displayed.

Comment: @MaximStogniy It seems you are using column date type to compare with carbon's timestamp, try to use `$date = (new Carbon\Carbon('2019-12-26'))->format('Y-m-d')`

Comment: I'm sorry, because I forgot to add "-> get ()" at the end of the request. And now everything works.

Comment: @MaximStogniy ok, glad u made it.

Comment: Just in case, I added date conversion with Carbon

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one

```
Model::where('assinged_date', '<=', $selected_date)
   ->orWhere('removal_date', '>=', $selected_date);
   ->get();
```